# Interface to choose how many results I want to see

Tags: usability, buttons, actions, dialog, results

Where I work we have this dialog box that comes up when you search for a certain word in the system:
[image]

If the user says 'no', instead of not loading any results, the system loads either 10.000 or 1.000 results depending on the value of available results in all.

The previous dialog box asked the user two questions, which was obviously very confusing because if the user chose 'no' the system would show 10.000 records and if they chose 'cancel' it wouldn't show anything and 'yes' the system would show all results:

[image]

I have tried to change the microcopy of the buttons but not sure this would work:

[image]

So my question is: **is there another way to let the user choose how many results they want to see in this case?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, remove the dialog box altogether. Users are conditioned to not read them.

Take them directly to the results page with proper pagination (loading a few results per page). If they need finer control over results shown, provide the dropdown option to choose how many results per page to load.

Comment: thanks, we'll go with this

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the alternative figures: 1000 or 10000? There are 8999 options in the middle. Isn't that too much?

If you want the application to be as custom as possible, why not let the user choose the number of elements to display?

[image]

This example makes the "Cancel" button redundant and simplify the design.

Or make a more interactive version:

[image]